# Converting a String to Int in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, atoi

I currently have an assignment that requires me to ask the user for a number between 1 and 999. When the user enters that data a newline is also saved with the input the user provided. Since the user enters data from stdin it is stored as a string. I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out how to convert that string to it proper integer. This is what i have so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
    .global _start
     _start:
        bl read
        ldr r0, =input
        ldr r3, =number

     _convert:
        ldr r1, [r0], #1
        cmp r1, #'\n'
        beq _exit
        sub r1, r1, #48
        strb r1, [r3], #1
      _exit:
         mov r7, #1
         swi 0
      read:
        mov r7, #3
        mov r0, #0
        mov r2, #4
        ldr r1, =input
        swi 0
        bx lr
      .data
      input:
         .space 4
      number:
         .space 3 //This is 3 because we are not saving the newline char
```

Comment: It's quite simple: `value = 0; for (char c : str) { value = value*10 + c - '0'; }`

Comment: Carlos, where are you multiplying the accumulator by 10 to make room for the new digit?

Comment: you can use shifts to multiply by 10 if you dont want to use the multiply instruction y = (x<<3)+(x<<1) or y=((x<<2)+x)<<1;  y = x*10 = x*(2+8) = x*2 + x*8